# Decile distributed independent variable, how to find the effects of each decile on dependent variable?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, deciles

I am doing a multilevel regression model, and my main independent variable is individual level income (distributed in 10 deciles). I have no problem running a model to find the effect of income on the dependent variable.

However, I want to find the separate effects from each of the ten deciles on the dependent variable, to see whether the effect is stronger or weaker in any of the deciles. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "separate effects" might be?  For instance, if one were studying the relationship between the heights and weights of adult people, what would be the "effect" on weight of people 150 cm tall compared to the "effect" of people 160 cm tall?

Comment: I am studying how income inequality affects political trust. I want to understand how differences in income affects respondents trust. So, I want to understand the "separate effects" between the richest deciles and poorest deciles. Like you say, the effect on weight of people 150 cm tall might be different than the effect on weight of people 160 cm tall.

Comment: Could you please provide a definition of what you mean by "effect of"?  Your use of that phrase appears to differ from what would ordinarily be understood in this context.

Comment: By "effect of", I mean the regression coefficient of income on trust

Comment: Therein lies the difficulty: since there is just a *single* regression coefficient in your model, it makes no sense to look for "separate effects."  One resolution is to generalize your model by, for instance, using a spline for income.